# Anatomically correct banshee

Tags: biology, mythical-creatures

The original, irish lore around banshees has it that they merely foretell the death of someone, but do not cause that death. American pop culture has changed this, so they do bring death and destruction - as seen in various media such as videogames, books (I remember there was a malicious one in some Harry Potter book) and cartoons. And they do that through screaming.

I am interested in the pop culture one. How do they bring about death and destruction? How can they be anatomically correct?

Since there is an element of legend and myth around banshees, it doesn't have to be the screaming that does the actual killing - but they need it for some evolutionary reason.

Comment: Why does everything have to be evolutionary? Honestly, not everything is genetic, or adaptive, or even beneficial. Some people are just destructive nihilistic arseholes.

Comment: I know, I am a destructive, nihilistic redacted myself. But in the case of banshees, at least the screaming part must be hereditary.

Comment: I like this question, but the title is a bit misleading.  This isn't so much about the *anatomy* of the banshee as the *evolution* and *function* of the banshee.  Your question is *How did they evolve and how do they bring about death and destruction?*  I would suggest changing the title

Comment: @cegfault alright, I took the evolution out of the game and emphasized anatomy.

Comment: Evolutionary biology 101: beware of unsustained [adaptationism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adaptationism). Natural selection is but *one* of the forces driving evolution; sexual selection and especially genetic drift are easily as important.

Comment: Very good answers here, for once I wish I could mark more than one as correct.

Answer (score 11):

**It's a hallucination caused by a parasite.**

The funny thing about banshees is that the original Irish legend (like just about every original legendary and mythical monster) had completely different banshees from modern day. You are correct that they couldn't kill people and would just foretell their death, but they also took the form of an attractive young woman. The creepier version generally had you meeting them when they were doing something like washing your funeral shrouds, except no one you were with could see them, and when you looked away then looked back, they disappeared with no trace of them, though of course, depending on the story occasionally it would be a woman singing.

So symptoms include: seeing things only you can see or hearing sounds only you can hear, and death within days. And that sounds like a hallucination to me, a hallucination strongly correlated to the victim's death within a day or so. So the anatomically correct banshee, what seems to me, is a parasite that infects the host's brain and starts hallucinating. And, like always, when I think up a horrifying disease and go looking for horrifying things in nature, it turns out to already exist and be worse. Let me introduce [*Naegleria fowleri*](http://blogs.discovermagazine.com/crux/2015/10/29/parasite-human-brain-control/#.XcG90TNKhPY), aka the 'brain-eating amoeba'. It's the reason you *never, under ANY circumstances, drink from still water* while hiking. (Among other things which are equally horrifying.)

Having one of these will result in a condition called naegleriasis. The amoeba migrates to the brain and starts eating through it. It takes up to a week to fully kill the host and symptoms include hallucination. Now, remember, since the banshee can only be seen and heard from people who will die within the day, the description of its form must be taken from the hallucinator. And at this point, I think it's more likely that it's a voice that's heard, the 'banshee parasite' causes an eerie singing voice when it's eating the host's brain. And then the host dies the next day. And it's not hard to believe that the placebo effect takes over to show the woman- in other words, since the population believes in a banshee, when it takes over their mind and they hear the hallucinated voice, they conjure the hallucinated woman because they know that's supposed to happen.

Answer (score 10):

### The causation (from the banshee's perspective) is backwards

A banshee doesn't scream at a person to cause their death.  A banshee screams at a person *that they know is going to die*.

Why this might be evolutionarily favourable is fairly straightforward.  Maybe they require fresh carrion as part of their breeding cycle - they lay eggs in the flesh, or have a symbiotic relationship with a carrion-eater, or somesuch.  If it's not plausible that the banshee itself to utilise the corpse in their breeding cycle, maybe they are infected with a parasite that does, and which causes pain to the host to trigger the screaming response when desirable.

The more challenging question is how the banshee *knows* that a person will imminently die.  Perhaps they have very acute sensitivity to human illnesses, or a slight clairvoyance.  Note that the screaming is not incompatible with the banshee *actually* causing death - by being a carrier of (the same or different) airborne diseases that are lethal to humans, for instance - only that they are (from the banshee's perspective) coincidental.

Comment: I've heard stories of cats at old folks' homes that can sense when a resident is about to pass away and will go and snuggle up to them during their final hours. I don't know how the cats are able to sense this either, but if true, it means it's possible for your banshee to sense it too.

Comment: If a banshee was to infect a human with an airborne disease, the best way would be to sneeze incessantly, not to start screaming at them.

Comment: It doesn't need to be a symbiotic relationship a carrion eater, it could be a parasitic one. A banshee notices that somebody's about to kick the bucket, lets out an ear-piercing scream, which is like a dinner bell for a certain species of feral rats living in the region, banshee starts pumping those rats with its eggs (or a copy of its disease) in whichever gruesome way you desire... The rat knows it's going to explode in a shower of banshee babies after a few months, but it also has a slightly higher chance of not starving until the next breeding season, so it's a net win for the rat anyways.

Answer (score 4):

**Resonance.**

You know that trick where opera singers can shatter a wine glass? They do that by singing at the glass's resonant frequency, causing it to vibrate until it shatters. [The same principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mechanical_resonance) has been responsible for the collapse of multiple bridges, and is theoretically capable of collapsing entire buildings.

All your banshees have to do is scream loud enough, for long enough, at *just* the right frequency. In order to produce such loud, long screams, your banshees would also need superhuman lung capacity, and probably specialised vocal chords in order to be able to produce the right frequencies every time.

As for why they would have evolved the ability to scream like this, perhaps they have a predator species or prey species with the ability to construct things, like beaver dams or rabbit warrens (or human dwellings... [*scare chord*]). They developed the resonant screams as a means of collapsing those structures, either as self-defense against the predator, or to trap the prey.

Answer (score 2):

For me, Renan seems to be asking for a banshee that would kill people on purpose, not just foretell their deaths, and needs a reasonable explanation for why their screaming comes into it. The most logical answer seems to be...

**That's how they hunt.**

We all know how deafening a good fire alarm can be, and that's not even designed to incapacitate us, quite the contrary. So by weaponising a potent voice, like that of howler monkeys, it could be used to disorientate or even paralyse the banshee's prey while the hunter descends on it and goes for the kill.

Some people are also sensitive to [certain notes and melodies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Musicogenic_epilepsy), so maybe by very precise adaptations, these banshees would find a note that can trigger a seizure/loss of conciousness in their target.

Answer (score 1):

**The banshees are screaming because they are happy.**

Maybe "whooping" would be a better term.  First the banshees set roller skates on the stairs, leave the potato salad out then put it away at the last minute, get people hooked on cigarettes -  death dealing things.  Then they get happy thinking about the setup.  Then they start cackling and whooping and shrieking.  If you actually lay eyes on one while she is screaming you will see that she is doing a shuffling little jig, making stabbing motions with an invisible knife.

They are just mean, those banshees.  But mean things get happy too.  Being mean makes them happy.

Answer (score 1):

You're interested in the pop culture one. So I'll ignore the foretelling of death and just concentrate on why they might evolve to cause injury / death by screaming.

The simplest explanation is that they evolved alongside a predator that hunted primarily using its hearing, perhaps because it was nocturnal. Natural selection selected predators for better and better hearing, to the point where extremely loud sounds could stun it. Thus natural selection also selected banshees who could scream loudly enough to stun the predators. To take it further, perhaps then natural selection selected predators who could tolerate louder sounds, banshees who could scream louder and so on in an evolutionary arms race. For whatever reason the predators died out long ago (or maybe they still exist too, in dark corners of the world) and we are left with banshees who have evolved a scream loud enough to injure or kill.